# QML C++ Signals-Slot not overloaded

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

I have spent the whole day on this code and couldn't figure out what is the problem.

This is the error:

```
* ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'cppReturnAnswer' with no type [-fpermissive]

* 'int HandleTextField::cppReturnAnswer(QVariant)' cannot be overloaded

* with 'void HandleTextField::cppReturnAnswer(QVariant)'
```

And this the code:

```
//handletextfield.h
class HandleTextField : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
signals:
    void cppReturnAnswer(QVariant data); // ERROR HERE
public slots:
    std::string text;
    QString color = QString::fromStdString(text);
    emit cppReturnAnswer(QVariant(color)); // ERROR HERE
};
```

which is used respectively in program

```
// in .. handletextfield.cpp
...
void HandleTextField::handleSubmitTextField(const QString &in)
{   qDebug() << "c++: HandleTextField::handleSubmitTextField:" << in;

    text="green";
    QString color = QString::fromStdString(text);
    emit cppReturnAnswer(QVariant(color));
}

// in main.cpp
...
QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().at(0);
QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);
// connect - from QML to C++ ---- WORKS NICE
QObject::connect(window, SIGNAL(submitTextField(QString)),
                     &handleTextField, SLOT(handleSubmitTextField(QString)));
// connect - from C++ to QML  ---- NOT WORKING
QObject::connect(&handleTextField,
                 SIGNAL(cppReturnAnswer(QVariant)),
                 window,
                 SLOT(qmlUpdateData(QVariant)));

// in main.qml
...
function qmlUpdateData(text){
    // hack(msg designer:: imperative code not supported in Qt Quick)
    page.color=text // gotdata from C++ backend
}
```

Any suggestions and comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: `emit cppReturnAnswer(QVariant(color));` <-- What is this doing in your class definition?!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Now it is fixed. Just had to delete from //handletextfield.h the three lines after slot; and add std::string text; to  handletextfield.cpp. Yeah...